# How can I get all the dimensions of the selected component in the assembly file in Solidworks?

Tags: solidworks

I wrote a macro to select a component by name from an assembly and then change its dimensions as required to automate the process.

Since I used dimension names, this script cannot be currently used for other similar assemblies.

My question is, how can I get all the dimensions of the selected component in the assembly file.

Including a part of my code here:

---

```
Dim vComponents As Variant
Dim vComp As Variant

Dim Part As Object



Set swApp = Application.SldWorks
Set Part = swApp.ActiveDoc

vComponents = Part.GetComponents(True)



For Each vComp In vComponents
Set swComp = vComp
If InStr(swComp.Name2, "_ST_") > 0 Then swComp.Select4 True, Nothing, False
Next


Set swSelMgr = Part.SelectionManager
Set swSelComp = swSelMgr.GetSelectedObjectsComponent4(1, -1)
Set swReferenceModel = swSelComp.GetModelDoc2

originalStello = swReferenceModel.Parameter("D7@Schizzo1").Value  // this is where I am hard coding the name
```

---

In the last line, you can see that I am getting the dimension value by hard coding its name. I would rather like to get all dimensions of the SELECTED component and then write logic to get a particular dimension from that list.

I started working with Solidworks API 2 days ago. Please help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could read all "Parameters" from the referenced model of your selected component like.
To do so you first have to get the ActiveConfiguration of the referenced model and then use GetParameters to fill the variant variables.

The variable vParamNames is containing the parameter names and the variable vParamValues is containing the belonging values. You maybe have to filter out the needed dimensions.

```
Dim swSelMgr As SldWorks.SelectionMgr
Set swSelMgr = Part.SelectionManager

Dim swSelComp As SldWorks.Component2
Set swSelComp = swSelMgr.GetSelectedObjectsComponent4(1, -1)

Dim swReferenceModel As SldWorks.ModelDoc2
Set swReferenceModel = swSelComp.GetModelDoc2

Dim swConfig As SldWorks.Configuration
Set swConfig = swReferenceModel.ConfigurationManager.ActiveConfiguration

Dim vParamNames As Variant
Dim vParamValues As Variant

swConfig.GetParameters vParamNames, vParamValues
```

Answer (score 4):

Another option is to traverse all display dimensions from all features

```
Function GetAllDimensions(vFeats As Variant) As Variant

    Dim swDimsColl As Collection
    Set swDimsColl = New Collection

    Dim i As Integer

    For i = 0 To UBound(vFeats)

        Dim swFeat As SldWorks.Feature
        Set swFeat = vFeats(i)

        Dim swDispDim As SldWorks.DisplayDimension
        Set swDispDim = swFeat.GetFirstDisplayDimension

        While Not swDispDim Is Nothing

            If Not Contains(swDimsColl, swDispDim) Then
                swDimsColl.Add swDispDim
            End If

            Set swDispDim = swFeat.GetNextDisplayDimension(swDispDim)
        Wend

    Next

    GetAllDimensions = CollectionToArray(swDimsColl)

End Function
```

Find the complete example [here](https://www.codestack.net/solidworks-api/document/dimensions/traverse-all/)